# How to remove the Java icon at JavaFX application start?

Tags: java, javafx-8

I'm having trouble with the start of an JavaFX application. When loading the application the `Icon` in the windows taskbar is the Java icon instead of my own icon for a split second.

```
@Override
public final void start(final Stage stage) {

    MainController controller = new MainController();
    Scene scene = new Scene(controller.getRoot());

    stage.setTitle("Geex");
    stage.getIcons().addAll(
            new Image(App.class.getResourceAsStream("/application/images/icon_16.png")),
            new Image(App.class.getResourceAsStream("/application/images/icon_32.png")),
            new Image(App.class.getResourceAsStream("/application/images/icon_48.png")),
            new Image(App.class.getResourceAsStream("/application/images/icon_64.png")),
            new Image(App.class.getResourceAsStream("/application/images/icon_128.png")),
            new Image(App.class.getResourceAsStream("/application/images/icon_256.png"))
    );
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setMinHeight(FRAME_HEIGHT);
    stage.setMinWidth(FRAME_WIDTH);
    stage.setMaximized(true);
    stage.show();

}
```